# Remove box-shadow of input from Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to remove box-shadow of all input elements by javascript. I have tried this but it does not work.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input').style.boxShadow = '';
```

Comment: no jQuery, mootools or else ?

Comment: I am a beginner, dont know jQuery yet. is it possible only with javascript?

Comment: Why can't you remove the styles in CSS?

Comment: getElementsByTagName returns an array which does not have 'style' property

Comment: @Martin: *"I am a beginner, dont know jQuery yet. is it possible only with javascript?"* jQuery is just a library of functions written in JavaScript using the various interfaces available in the browser. There's nothing jQuery can do that you can't do without jQuery. (Using a library can save you time, though.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT'), function(el) {
     el.style.boxShadow = '';
});
```

`getElementsByTagName` returns `NodeList`, which is sort of like an `Array`; has `length` property, and is enumerable, but has no other goodies.

And here's an alternative which you should prefer:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
var len = elements.length;
for(var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
 elements[i].style.boxShadow = '';
}
```

But If I were you, I'd invest my time into learning jQuery, because of this:

```
$("input").css("boxShadow", "none");
```

Comment: You don't have to go via `slice` if you just want `forEach`; `Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('input'), function (e) {console.log(e);});`

Answer (score 0):

> The getElementsByTagName() method returns a collection of all elements
>   in the document with the specified tag name, as a NodeList object.

you can quickly convert NodeList object to array by this way `[...NodeList]`

1. convert NodeList object to array
   `[...document.getElementsByTagName('input')]`
2. then use `forEach` to loop through elements

full code:-

```
[...document.getElementsByTagName('input')].forEach( function(el){
    el.style.boxShadow = 'none';
});
```

---

Example:-

```js
var NodeList = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
[...NodeList].forEach( function( el, i ) {
  if ( i === 1 ) return; // keep a box shadow for second input
  if ( el.classList.contains('shadow') ) return; // keep a box shadow for shadow class
  el.style.boxShadow = 'none';
});
```

```css
input {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}
```

```html
<input name="input-1" type="text" value="Input 1" /><br/>
<input name="input-2" type="text" value="Input 2" /><br/>
<input name="input-3" type="text" value="Input 3" /><br/>
<input name="input-4" type="text" value="Input 4" /><br/>
<input class="shadow" name="input-5" type="text" value="Input 5" /><br/>
<input name="input-6" type="text" value="Input 6" />
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Code-only answers are discouraged here, as they don't provide insight into how the problem was solved. Please update your solution with an explanation of how your code solves the OP's problem :)

Comment: @Joel I hope this changes explains the solution. thanks:)